# Get 10 values of topic I'm subscribing to

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I'm trying to create a loop to get the average of special informations of a pointcloud.

```
void

 GetParameters::cloud_CB_Parameter_calc(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& cloud_msgs){
    ROS_DEBUG("Received input cloud")
  
try{



ROS_INFO("Cloud-Callback in progress ...");

//  lastDynamicUpdate_ = cloud_msgs->header.stamp;

  // transform cloud_msgs to worldframe
  // ------------------------------------
  tfListener_.waitForTransform(strFixedFrame_, cloud_msgs->header.frame_id, cloud_msgs->header.stamp, tfTimeout_);

  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 ff_cloud;
  pcl_ros::transformPointCloud(strRobotFrame_, *cloud_msgs, ff_cloud, tfListener_);



// transform ff_cloud (worldframe) to PointXYZ-Cloud temp_cloud
  // -------------------------------------------------------------
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2 pcl_pc2;
  pcl_conversions::toPCL(ff_cloud,pcl_pc2);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr temp_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(pcl_pc2,*temp_cloud);

[... here i calclulate the roll/pitch values for each momental pointcloud ...]

// add the parameter value for each i to a history-vector
    // -------------------------------------------------------
    history_pitch.push_back(pitch_degree);
    history_roll.push_back(roll_degree);
    history_zdistance.push_back(d_z);
}

calc_and_publish_Parameters();   // here I want to calculate the average of the history vectors
}
```

In the following parts of the code I process the data of this pointcloud. I want to get the average of the pitch/and roll angles of the ground plane I get out of this PointCloud.

In another get_parameters_node.cpp I call a main-function and do ros::spin() in it. So I get the values in a open loop. but my goal is to run the node as an function that returns only one value of roll/ pitch

I already tried to build a for-loop around the call-back method, but that didn't worked, like i got a time delay to the laserscanner-topic.

What can i do to do the "callback-process and the calculation of the angles". I already implemented a method to do the average. The only thing I don't know is how to do the subscribe and writing to the vector loop only 20 times and then stop the method for calculating the average of the 20 values.

Thank you very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283003/get-10-values-of-topic-i%27m-subscribing-to/) by [DBServ](https://answers.ros.org/users/33529/dbserv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: see #q261816 for a duplicate of your question, but with an answer in Python.

---

Simplest (but with a bit of duplicated effort): create a `std::list` or `std::vector` that holds incoming samples (ie: PointClouds). Then every so often (ie: after `N` new samples), run your averaging algorithm.

To make it nice: add a sliding window approach (ie: throw away/pop the `M` last samples after each averaging run).

---

With a bit more reuse: make use of the `message_filters` package. For a simple cache, you could look at the [Cache](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Cache) filter.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DBServ](https://answers.ros.org/users/33529/dbserv/) on 2018-02-19**:
Thank you very much for the idea with cache and vector. I still got a history-vector where I add the value of the pointcloud but right now only in a open loop. I want to stop the loop for subscribing and calculation and build after that the average of the values. I add the full code above!